# Testing touch functionality in Emulator

Tags: android, debugging, touch

I try to develop a App for android. I have the following code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main); 
    CardImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.CardImage);
    CardImage.setOnTouchListener(this);
}

public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)  
{ 
    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
    {
        System.out.println("Touch!");
    }

    return true;
}
```

How can i debug the Ontouch  function in the emulator? I tried to drag the image switch the mouse but nothing happend.

Thanks for you help!

Comment: does you activity implement onTouchListener?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code (Note : not tested)

```
 CardImage.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {  
         @Override
         public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
          int X = (int) event.getX();
          int Y = (int) event.getY();
          int action = event.getAction();
          if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
          TranslateAnimation anim = new TranslateAnimation(CardImage.getLeft(),X,CardImage.getTop()
          ,Y);
          anim.setFillAfter(true);
          anim.setDuration(1000);
          CardImage.startAnimation(anim);
          }   
          return true;
         }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

It has just worked with the following code.

```
public class TestTouch extends Activity implements View.OnTouchListener{    
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ImageView  iv = new ImageView(this);
    iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.flag); // my image
    iv.setOnTouchListener(this);
    setContentView(iv);
}

public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
{
    System.out.println(event.getAction());
    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
    {
        System.out.println("Touch!");
    }    
    return true;
}    
}
```